# How to get Gmail/browser to remember login?

Tags: firefox

I am using firefox 3.6.22.

I have several Gmail accounts. In the past, when I would go to the Gmail login, it would remember all my logins. All I would need to do would be to enter first letter and it would pick up the rest.

Now it has stopped doing this. I can still type the whole login (if I remember it) and the password and get in.

Why did it lose the ability to remember, and how do I get it back?

Comment: When you say: `All I would need to do would be to enter first letter and it would pick up the rest` ... are you talking about use of Auto-complete on login page ?

Answer (score 1):

Google recently changed the URL for the Gmail login page, and so your Firefox does not have any saved user/password data for the
new URL. If you have your Firefox options set to "remember passwords", you should get a dropdown bar asking if you want to save
the password whenever you fill out a login form on a webpage. ONce you have logged in to Gmail under all your accounts there
(and of course telling Firefox to remember them), you should be good to go. You can use Tools>Options>Security>Saved Passwords
to delete your old Gmail user/password data items.

Comment: Are you saying that since gmail url has now changed so Firefox is not associating the new url with the previously saved logins/pw? If so how can I tell update the old url to the new? is that what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have something clearing your browser cache. I don't have that version of browser so I can't walk through the menus but you want enter options and verify you have cookies enabled and that the browser is not setup to clear it's cookies on exit.

For multiple GMail accounts it appears there have been some mechanical changes in how they manage them. I cannot personally have my Google Apps account (old school email) and my personal GMail open in the same browser. This is something that we can't necessarily do anything about at this point from what I understand. Work arounds include using a different browser for each account or using incognito tabs for each one however they wouldn't remember their passwords.